# Combine two tables in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have:

Table1:

```
|-----|-----------|---------|
| ID  | Last Name | Country |
| 200 | Abc       |Germany  |
| 444 | JHk       | Norway  |
|-----|-----------|---------|
```

Table 2:

```
|-------|----------|
| Month | Year     |
| 10    | 2020     |
| 11    | 2020     |
|-------|----------|
```

I want to have just 1 table like this:

Table 3:

```
|-----|-----------|---------|-------|------|
| ID  | Last name | Country | Month | Year |
| 200 | Abc       | Germany | 10    | 2020 |
| 444 | JHk       | Norway  | 10    | 2020 |
| 200 | Abc       | Germany | 11    | 2020 |
| 444 | JHk       | Norway  | 11    | 2020 |
|-----|-----------|---------|-------|------|
```

In SQL it would be:

SELECT * FROM Table1, Table2;

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Power Query Editor** and follow these below steps-

**Step 1:** Create a **Custom Column** in **Table1** with a fixed value 1 as below-

[image]

**Step 2:** Create a **Custom Column** in **Table2** with a fixed value 1 as shown above.

**Step 3:** Merge **Table2** in **Table1** using new column as shown below-

[image]

**Step 4:** Expand column and keep only month and year column and your output will be as below-

[image]

Comment: But table1 and table2 are linked to an external source. Is any possibility of doing that without modifying those tables?

Comment: Adding a calculated column will not change the data source and does not affect anything beyond showing an extra field in Power BI. If that is an issue, just hide the fields from Client Tools by selecting the columns and select Hide.

Comment: Calculated/custom column will not impact anything as @Kupokev confirmed.

Comment: And what if I have in table2 multiple times the same value (for example, 10) and I just want to show it 1 time in merged table?

Comment: Can I keep just unique rows of month? I have day and month, so I have 30 rows per month, approximately

Comment: This depends up to which level you actually need.